# XmlDataProvider в UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, xmlparser

Добрый день, сегодня мне понадобилось портировать приложение, которое работает с XML из приложения WPF в UWP. Первое, что бросилось мне в глаза - отсутствие класса XmlDataProvider.
Кто нибудь может подсказать мне, можно ли парсить XML родными средствами, или же понадобится написать парсер самому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться Linq To XML, в UWP оно хорошо работает.

Comment: То, что нужно. Благодарю за ответ.